# How to update progressbar via a listener in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, events, console, laravel-5

I have a pretty basic `command` which dispatches a `job`, which in turn triggers an `event` and the `event` has a `listener` assigned to it via the `EventServiceProvider`.

All the parts work properly. I have no issues in the functionality other than that to show the progress as the date is inserted into the table.

Basically, the job populates my `model` and saves the data to a table in my db.
I iterate over an array to achieve this. Within the iteration I trigger the `event` using `\Event::fire( new event())`

Now, in the `listener` I can get the newly created row and can print out its id as i run the command but I want the `command` to display a progressbar using the  `$this->output->createProgressbar()`

How can get the data from the `listener` into my `command` where I can do a `$progress->advance()`

Comment: Events are designed around being used asynchronously, so achieving what you're after might be cumbersome.

One way to do it is to pass the command down the chain as part of the DTO : `new event($this)` where `$this` is the command, and can have a method to be called when the progress bar should be updated. On the down side, it might lead to some tight coupling.

Comment: Thanks @MikeStivala, tight coupling is my fear. There must be some way.

Comment: Combining events with a command is making your problem harder.

Can you forego events somehow?

Comment: No because I have to display a progressbar of how many items have bben processed so far. ANd the process is a long one